# What historical crime did Whitebeard Pirates commit?

Tags: one-piece

In episode 1068 of One Piece, a member of **CP-0** was seen talking to **Izou**, where the former mentioned that Whitebeard pirates have committed a historical crime.

[image: Screenshot]

In both anime and manga, the biggest battles Whitebeard pirates fought were the Marineford War for Ace and the Payback War against Blackbeard, both of which weren't related to World Government.

Then what exactly could it be?

Comment: Is it not possible that this will be revealed in a future episode?

Comment: Since Whitebeard pirates are almost all dead, I am not sure.

Comment: Also worth noticing that it is "Marine talk". Robin's "crime" is being alive, so was Ace's, Luffy first act of piracy was "helping Arlong on Conomi Island", Don Flamingo was a good guy and so was Crocodile as long as they were still useful, nothing weird happened during the void century, no one wiped any ancient civilization, the Celestial Dragons are a nice and welcoming group of adorable people that deserve to be loved and protected and most importantly [spoiler for manga > 1044](http://the.Gomu.Gomu.No.Mi.is.a.real.existing.fruit)

Answer (score 1):

**The Marines are part of World Government**, and arguably they're its most active branch. Therefore assaulting their headquarters and laying waste to them is already a crime against WG of historic proportion.

---

I don't know if your subtitles are an official translation. The English translation of chapter 1038 I am familiar with (it would be interesting to know what the original Japanese says) speaks of *historic crimes* of Whitebeard's crew, which may just refer to the total of their criminal activities.

Of those we aren't shown much (in point of fact, in chapter 965 we see the Moby Dick fleeing from Marine warships because Whitebeard thought that fighting them was pointless), but it stands to reason that while conquering and mantaining their infamous *turf*, the Whitebeard Pirates would evict WG officers, on occasion. It also stands to reason that plundering WG cargos would be part of their income.

I'll leave aside the issue of whether or not they were helping a world-class terrorist - which Whitebeard techincally was because of his previous affiliation with Rocks - escape capture, because a large portion of Rocks' story has been classified by the WG.

Comment: It may refer to the total number of their criminal activities, and it makes sense that they attached WG cargo occasionally for the loot for maintaining themselves and towns under their flag. I highly doubt Rocks part though, because most likely only Whitebeard was affiliated with Rocks from his crew which he built after God Valley.

Comment: @Zero Helping a criminal escape capture may very well be a crime in OP, but as I said I don't want to speculate much further about that because WG ultimately wants those events not to be kept on record.